# Did the Enterprise' warp core breach after the swarm ships knocked the saucer out of orbit?

Tags: star-trek-beyond

I may have missed some dialogue, but did the warp core breach after Krall's attack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Movie:**

There's nothing in the dialogue to suggest what happened to the engineering section after Krall's attack. We certainly don't *see* it explode.

---

**Speculation time:**

The ship enters orbit around Altamid. A few minutes later, the saucer section, under its own power and trying to evade the swarm, entered the planet's gravitational field and crash-landed.

With no way of moving itself and no crew on board, it seems likely that the engineering section (and its attendant warp core) simply remained in orbit. There's really no good reason why it should explode.